# Converting adobe lens correction for lensfun / darktable

Tags: darktable, linux, lens-correction, lensfun

I'm trying to import Adobe's lens profiles to lensfun (for use with darktable). I'm using darktable 2:2.6.2-1 on Arch Linux installed through pacman, which brought down  lensfun 0.3.2-7. (I'm not using the darktable-git or lensfun-git packages). As such, the lensfun-convert-lcp script isn't in my install. I separately cloned lensfun from github, and running it against Adobe DNG converter's profiles successfully generates _lcps.xml. However, in the root node of this file, I see

```
<lensdatabase version="2">
```

I've run lensfun-update-data, and the database in /var/lib/lensfun-updates/version_1/*.xml files have

```
<lensdatabase version="1">
```

Looking at some attributes, the schemas are different. e.g. distortion has k1, k2, k3 in one and a, b, c in the other.

I was wondering how I could get these profiles to load under darktable.

===========================================

## Update

So this is what I've tried so far:

1. Uninstalled darktable and lensfun. Installed lensfun-git. Installed darktable. There's now no module for lens correction at all :( lensfun.get_database_version() is 2.
2. Uninstalled darktable and lensfun. Installed lensfun-git and darktable-git. Uses lensfun db v2, and everything is picked up. Darktable UI looks a bit naff on 4k monitor. lensfun.get_database_version() is 2.
3. Installing darktable and lensfun (neither git) makes things work, but the adobe converted lcps.xml stuff doesn't get picked up. lensfun.get_database_version() is 1.

Is there a way to get darktable (not darktable-git) to use lensfun-git? Or for lensfun to pick up v2 databases when lensfun.get_database_version() is returning 1?

## Update 2

In scenario 1 (lensfun-git + darktable non-git), launching darktable from the command line gives me:

```
[iop_load_module] failed to open operation `lens': liblensfun.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

## Update 3

I created a symlink for the missing file to liblensfun.so.2, and darktable picked up everything fine. Steps in the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what works for me is:

1. yaourt -S lensfun-git  -> uninstalls lensfun (non-git in the process).
2. cd /lib
3. sudo ln -s liblensfun.so.2 liblensfun.so.1
4. Launch darktable.

I do get a connection refused error when runnin lensfun-update-data, but seeing that the updates and infrequent, and that my lenses are all in Adobe's profiles, I'm happy with this.

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe profiles, you need DB version 2.  The differences are small, however: Besides the Adobe profiles, the `<real-focal-length>` tag became an attribute of `<distortion>`.

Darktable won’t care which DB version you use, In particular, Adobe profiles will work with any Darktable version, as along is it supports the API of current Lensfun.

Comment: I've updated the question with what I'm seeing. darktable-git with lensfun-git seems to pick up v2 databases, but nothing else seems to work.