# Lens corrections from lightroom .lcp to darktable .xml

Tags: darktable, windows, lens-correction, windows-10, lensfun

My aim is to convert lens correction file .lcp (adobe lightroom) to use it in darktable. I downloaded lensfun database with lensfun-convert-lcp (it has no extension) regarding [this link](https://darktable-users.narkive.com/6Ido7XLE/adobe-lcp-profiles-in-darktable) and have no idea what next. I have read [similar thread related to linux](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108620/converting-adobe-lens-correction-for-lensfun-darktable).
I use darktable 4.2.0 so probably it uses newer lensfun database than this from 2015. It works on windows 10 machine.